# Grafana: SQL query - Apply "filter" to "count"

Tags: sql, grafana

I am trying to apply a filter to "count" in my SQL query but just can't figure out the right way to do it.

[image]

The query of the left table shows the different error levels that an error type can have. "0 to 3" in my case, where 0 means information and 3 means critical_error.

```
SELECT
  stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) AS ERROR_Level,
  stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 2) AS ERROR_Type
FROM alerts
```

The query of the right table displays the overall error count. (I added some random numbers to the real numbers for demonstration purposes.)
The 1st column displays the error type and the 2nd column the total error count.
Beginning with the 3rd column I would like to filter for only errors that are defined as level 3.
The next column error level 2 and so on...

```
SELECT
  stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 2) AS ERROR_Type,
  COUNT(alerts.Source)+100 AS ERROR_Count,
  COUNT(alerts.Source)+73 AS ERROR_Critical,
#  COUNT(alerts.Source) FILTER(WHERE stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) = 3) AS critical,
  COUNT(alerts.Source)+30 AS ERROR_Warning
#  COUNT(alerts.Source) FILTER(WHERE stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) = 2) AS warning
FROM alerts
GROUP BY ERROR_Type
```

As you can see in the code above...
`stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1)` prints out the error levels
`stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 2)` prints out the error types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using SUM.

```
SELECT
  stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 2) AS error_type,
  COUNT(alerts.Source) AS total,
  SUM(IF(stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) = 3,1,0)) AS critical_errors,
  SUM(IF(stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) = 2,1,0)) AS errors,
  SUM(IF(stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) = 1,1,0)) AS warnings,
  SUM(IF(stringsplit(alerts.Source, " - ", 1) = 0,1,0)) AS informations
FROM alerts
GROUP BY ERROR_Type
```